# How can I effectively destroy bridges?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

Previously when playing as the Russians you could destroy bridges by having Engineers use their Plant Demolition Charges perk, this would take out most in one shot.  However it seems now that this only does minimal damage to it at all.

Since the British Forces DLC (which I do not have btw), is there a new method of taking down bridges quickly and effectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be nerfed continues to be so.   The only way I've found is using anti-tank mines and / or bringing anti-tank guns to the bridges, destroying them, and then disbanding the units.